# What's vague about this Question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm here referring to [a Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10108/disqus-analogs-comments-platforms-closed) that asks for equivalents of Disqus. What's so vague about it to justify it getting closed?

Answer (score 6):

Being vague is only one of the options available for that close reason.

It seems to be closed for being overly broad and not being specific enough to reach *one* acceptable answer adding to the unfavourable list of X questions.

If this were edited to include why and how this needs to be discussed to reach some conclusion then maybe it can be reopened. Amass enough reputation so you and other users who have interest in this question can reopen it.

Comment: You guys sound like this sort of thing has been discussed before on meta.SO (please provide a link if you have). Do you have links? Your answer makes sense, but I think you guys are being harsh. If I'm using X, it's very valid if I wanna know alternatives, regardless of reason. Curiosity is enough.

Comment: @Tshepang meta.stackoverflow.com is for stackexchange-wide issues (for example making api calls). meta.webapps is the official meta of webapps. Any meta-discussion happens here and is not ruled by any other meta (though guidelines/structures may have been replicated/refitted to suit the needs of the webapps community).

Comment: @Tshepang for list of X please read http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/354/detailed-list-questions-and-cw

Answer (score 4):

It's a typical "List of X" non-question that is just asking people to throw down what other commenting systems they know of.

- No reasons are given for wanting to know
- No qualifiers are laid out to work with (even then recommendations end up being popularity contests)
- Question is bare, no effort is made to clarify anything

A question mark at the end of a sentence doesn't make it a valid question.

Comment: see my response to @phwd